# Programming SaaS applications

Tags: c#, .net, saas

I want to build a SaaS application, but I am confused at how to technically program it.

Are there any .NET based frameworks to build SaaS applications, helping in managing the different configurations.

Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363361/multi-tenant-saas-resources

Comment: Thanks for that resource! :) 
Which framework did you end up using?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SaaS means **Software As A Service**

So, any software that you can produce that, instead of selling it as a final package, you sell it as a service will go directly to that category.

For example, you can buy a CRM Application that you can install in your computer and that's it... kind'a Office, that's a software as a product, but, you can buy a CRM application and pay every month (kind'a SalesForce).

You as a **user** do not need to worry with IT infrastructure, Servers, Updates, etc ...

You as a **developer** provide not a simple product to be installed but a resource to be consumed, where you will be in charge of providing hosting, updates, etc.

That's a Software As A Service, and not As A Product.

---

There are tools to ease or developing line like Patterns for SaaS, Database Migrations, Farming, etc, but essentially it's this.

In the **.NET World**, and if you want to read more about this, I would strongly suggest [Mike's](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com) blog post, [part 1](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/11/multi-tenancy-part-1-strategy.html) and [part 2](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/11/multi-tenancy-part-2-components-and.html)... as well download and check the [source of he's code](http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/)

---

A good way to start.

> **Video** on [Multi-tenant ASP.NET MVC Projects](http://vimeo.com/9217399) from [Rob](http://codeofrob.com) in [DDD8](http://developerdeveloperdeveloper.com/ddd8/)

---

**Let me talk about my story** a little bit. Seeing for the first time the video above I realize that I'm currently publish to the public a multi-tenant SaaS application and I did not knew anything about SaaS specificly, I just started coding with my own logic.

I ended up with 3 main products, an address book and a calendar (those are the real products) and an Administration (add users, set properties in a nice control panel way), and I choose to follow the **ASP.NET MVC 3** road using custom domain names.

I have in my route something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ClientRequest", "{cliurl}/{id}",
    new { cliurl = "none", controller = "ABook", action = "Index", id = "none" }
);
```

And in my controller I load all configuration of that user using the `{cliurl}` property of the URL, those names are set up by the user in the control panel, and they will ending up being:

```
http://abook.domain.com/myclientname/myencodeduser
```

for a real client domain and encode user:

```
http://abook.domain.com/demo1/iHiMFrQq0AdYBR45Q2kvww
```

plus I give them the ability of each user change it's own settings using:

> http://abook.domain.com/demo1/iHiMFrQq0AdYBR45Q2kvww**/settings**

or see a log of it's actions

> http://abook.domain.com/demo1/iHiMFrQq0AdYBR45Q2kvww**/about**

So, it's pretty rudimentary but I ended up having a nice solution without reading anything specific on SaaS, as I'm happy with the result, I'm just sharing the experience.

Comment: +1 Nice answer :).. in adition to that, can you tell me how can I implement a Pay-as-you-go architecture for the my SaaS app.